# Varistor in series with resistor

Tags: varistor

[image: schematic and MOV characteristic curves]

I am trying to figure out the behavior of an MOV and a resistor in series.

When we connect a resistor in series with an LED to a DC voltage source, in order to determine the resistor value, we subtract the voltage drop of the LED from the voltage source and the result we divide by the current that we want to flow in the circuit.

If we change the resistor value, the current will decrease or increase, but the voltage drop on the LED will remain the same.

If I connect a varistor (MOV) in series with a resistor to a voltage source and change the resistor value will the voltage drop on the varistor stay the same?

For example: If I connect to 500VDC source to a MOV-14D431R in series with a 70kΩ resistor (see picture,) the voltage drop on the varistor will be 430V (rated voltage,) the voltage drop on the resistor will be 70V, and the current will be 1mA, which fits the specifications.

If I change the resistor to 1.5MΩ, which will drop the current to 46uA, will the varistor voltage still be 430V (similar to the LED situation,) even though the current is very small (46uA,) or will the voltage drop on the MOV change to 300V? As can be seen in the picture, the voltage drop on the varistor at 46uA is ~300V on the graph, so at this current, the voltage on the varistor can be only around 300V.

What is the correct option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something around there.  Note two things:

1. The curve in this region is specifying maximum leakage.  A given part may draw less current and thus have a higher voltage (and less across the resistor).  The point you measure will not in general fall on the curve shown.  But it will always fall above or on it.
2. Especially for the 1.5M case, mind your meter's internal resistance, probably 10M.  This reduces the Thevenin equivalent voltage available from the source, or shunts current away from the MOV -- how ever you wish to phrase it.  A nulling measurement may be more accurate (measure between a lower impedance source, like a ~100kΩ resistor divider, and the node of interest; adjust divider until meter reads zero, then measure the divider's output).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2bGEN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is how you perform a nulling measurement.  R1 and MOV1 are the components as you were testing them, 100k or 1.5M or whatever.  The pot R3 needs to be rated for V1's voltage, and is adjusted to read zero on the meter.  R4 represents the meter's resistance.

Note if you set R3 to zero or max (wiper to GND or +V), you get the circuit you started with, measuring the voltage across MOV1 or R1 respectively.  R4 then is in parallel with one or the other, explaining the discrepancy.

Adjust R3 until the measurement reads zero.  Then R3 is set to the same voltage, and the current through the meter is zero so the reading is completely undisturbed.  You can then measure the voltage on R3 separately.  Though you still have the problem with its resistance, if it's a large value like 1M.  What you can do is measure from +V to R3, then R3 to GND, and average the two readings.

Comment: Also, the characteristic curves are for a new varistor. If it has been subjected to overload transients, its resistance will decrease, and it will draw more current. Thus, it may be a good idea to us a series resistor to monitor the current, and provide a warning when it exceeds a safe level. A series fuse is also advisable, and an indicator lamp across the fuse can show that the transient protection is no longer present.

Comment: @Tim Williams,Can you add a circuit diagram that shows how to connect the 100k ohm resistor divider to the node and to my circuit?Thanks.

Comment: @xchcui Got it.

Comment: @Tim Williams.Yes,thank you.